# Moving shapefiles to folder using ArcMap ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder

How do I move the created shapefiles (black circles) into the folder (red circle) within ModelBuilder?

[image]

Comment: Why not change the output file paths in the Clip and Select tools? Otherwise use Copy Features or Featureclass to Featureclass.

Comment: Use the name of the variable in the path, it looks like %Lotplan (3)%\GLM_Clip.shp etc.. Though I'd rename Lotplan (3) to OutputFolder and make your output path %OutputFolder%\GLM_Clip.shp etc for clarity.

Comment: Also make the output of Create Folder a precondition to the rest of the model, this ensures the folder exists before the rest runs.